# Is there any way to save my marigold plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, marigold

[image: Dying Marigold Plant]

I bought this marigold plant with some flower buds a few weeks ago. During the first few days, the leaves were fine.  Sadly, once the flower bloomed, the leaves started to look like this. I do not know why this happened and how to solve the problem.

From the beginning I used the tip of my finger to press and understand how dry the soil was, before watering it. Then I got a suggestion from a friend to place it away from the sun, so I did that, without any success. During that time the soil became a little dry so I watered it.

I never grew marigold plants before, so I lack experience.
If someone provides a helpful suggestion along with an explanation, I would really appreciate that!

Comment: Marigolds, I have a fresh dead one on  my balcony. I suspect they need a lot of light.

Comment: They need good amount of sun. Marigolds don't do well without direct sun. They need 5-6 hours of direct sunlight. The problem is you still have the plant planted in the poor soil which is probably clay. I have grown 5 marigolds from flower seeds and they are good growing. I can share images tomorrow if you want. If that helps. Water should be given when the soil dries.